# BeautifulSoup returning 'None'

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get a list of reviews from the G2 website using BeautifulSoup. However, for some reason, when I run the code below, it says that 'reviews' is 'NoneType'. I can't figure this out because it clearly shows the class name in the HTML from the website (see the picture below). I have used this exact syntax to webscrape from other sites and it has worked so I have no idea why it is returning NoneType. I tried to use 'find_all' and return the length of the list (number of reviews), but that also shows nonetype. I am super confused. Please help!

```
response = requests.get('https://www.g2.com/products/mailchimp/reviews?filters%5Bcomment_answer_values%5D=&order=most_recent&page=1')
text = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


num_reviews = 500

reviews = text.find('div', attrs={'class': 'paper paper--white paper--box mb-2 position-relative border-bottom '})
print(reviews)
```

[image: Attached div screenshot]

Comment: Does <div class='paper paper--white paper--box mb-2 position-relative border-bottom ' appear in response.text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass headers to the HTTP request. It's detecting that you're not a browser, if you print the variable text out, you'll see that.

### Parsed HTML you get

```
...
<h1>Pardon Our Interruption...</h1>
<p>
                        As you were browsing something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen:
                    </p>
<ul>
<li>You're a power user moving through this website with super-human speed.</li>
<li>You've disabled JavaScript and/or cookies in your web browser.</li>
<li>A third-party browser plugin, such as Ghostery or NoScript, is preventing JavaScript from running. Additional information is available in this <a href="http://ds.tl/help-third-party-plugins" target="_blank" title="Third party browser plugins that block javascript">support article</a>.</li>
...
```

So passing headers, is enough to mimic browser activity.
To grab the headers

### Code Example

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.g2.com',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cookie': '__cfduid=df6514ad701b86146978bf17180a5e6f01597144255; events_distinct_id=822bbff7-912d-4a5e-bd80-4364690b2e06; amplitude_session=1597144258387; _g2_session_id=424bfbe09b254b1a9484f50b70c3381c; reese84=3:BJ8QXTaIa+brQNrbReKzww==:n5v0tg/Q590u2q44+xAi7rnSO1i2Kn7Lp1Ar+2SCMJF5HiBJNqLVR3IPzPF0qIqgxpWjZ9veyhywY4JNSbBOtz5sJOwEecGJE9tT+NInof+vlP3hKTb6bqA3cvAf6cfDIrtEmhI0Dsjoe3ct3NtwvvcA9p8FXHPR7PAFP42nWqAAfDH88vj0hQwWlIjio/fT4g5iDsT1qZH3alC8ZbUhOURKNk9JUz2sBz+RjgkRyctO0VTGzjxmHCd2r40WJqWjVDwRmBl+/msW+/V0PW93vjFs45bMD63D5Q4JeRreBxkAN9ufIajaV0MmkYbxlFnwIZ3cEBHi/X76n+PvAobd5/UgCwgUIvt/P4pl7NEcDWR/ORaZ8gLPl4HbuQaRhEVd23Ez5OBnYFP1wjqLT/ECDkRzQq0Nn8U6qVbMO25Hp6U=:/JrPeXs0AKDQw5FlG3vKQX1dPIsF/TEXTLgQ+mktyAo=; ue-event-segment-983a43a0-1c10-4dfb-96d7-60049c0dcd62=W1siL3VzZXJzL2NvbnNlbnQvc2VsZWN0ZWQiLHsiY29uc2VudF90eXBlIjoi%0AY29va2llcyIsImdyYW50ZWQiOiJ0cnVlIn0sIjk4M2E0M2EwLTFjMTAtNGRm%0AYi05NmQ3LTYwMDQ5YzBkY2Q2MiIsIlVzZXIgQ29uc2VudCBTZWxlY3RlZCIs%0AWyJhbXBsaXR1ZGUiXV1d%0A',
    'if-none-match': 'W/"3658e5098c91c183288fd70e6cfd9028"',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.g2.com/products/mailchimp/reviews', headers=headers)

text = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


num_reviews = 500

reviews = text.select('div[class*="paper paper--white paper--box"]')

print(len(reviews))
```

### Output

```
25
```

### Explanation

Sometimes in order to make an HTTP request, it's necessary to pass either headers, user agent, cookies, parameters. You can play about with this, I must admit I was lazy and just sent the entire headers. Essentially you're trying to mimic a browser request by using the requests package. Sometimes it's abit more nuanced in detecting a bot.

Here i've inspected the page and gone to network tools. There's a tab called doc. I've then copied that request, by right clicking the request and clicking COPY curl(bash). As I said i'm lazy so I've pasted that into curl.trillworks.com which converts this into a nice python format as well the boilerplate for a request.

I've modified your script slightly as it was quite a long attribute

the CSS selector `div[class*=""]` grabs any element with class `""` you specific.